# Creating a foreign key in Entity Framework using SQLite

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core, maui

I'm using Entity Framework Core 7 in a .NET Maui app with SQLite to store relational data using two data models.

`CheckList`:

```
using SQLite;
using SQLiteTest.DataModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace SQLiteTest.DataModels
{
    public class CheckList
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int CheckListID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [SQLite.MaxLength(50)]
        public string name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<CheckListItem> CheckListItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`CheckListItem`:

```
using SQLite;
using SQLiteTest.DataModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace SQLiteTest.DataModels
{
    public class CheckListItem
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int CheckListItemID { get; set; }

        public string ItemText { get; set; }
        public bool isChecked { get; set; }
        public int ItemOrder { get; set; }

        // foreign key
        [ForeignKey("CheckList")]
        public int CheckListID { get; set; }
        public CheckList CheckList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xml:

```
using SQLite;
using SQLiteTest.DataModels;

namespace SQLiteTest;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private SQLiteConnection _database;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var dbPath = Path.Combine(@"D:\TESTDATA", "dbtest.db");
        _database = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);

        _database.CreateTable<CheckList>();
        _database.CreateTable<CheckListItem>();
    }
}
```

I get an exception on:

```
_database.CreateTable<CheckList>();
```

> Exception: System.NotSupportedException: 'Don't know about system.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1 [SQLiteTest.DataModels.CheckListItem]'

If I remove:

```
public ICollection<CheckListItem> CheckListItems { get; set; }
```

Then it creates the table, but not the foreign key. I believe the error has to do with `CheckList` not knowing what a type `CheckListItem` is. If I create `CheckListItem` first:

```
_database.CreateTable<CheckListItem>();
```

I get the exception on that line:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Don't know about SQLiteTest.DataModels.CheckList'

However, it does resolve in code and compiles without warning or error. Is this error thrown because table `CheckListItems` doesn't exist in database yet?

Updated after running migrations (looks like the foreign key relationships is built?)

```
public partial class InitialCreate : Migration
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "List",
            columns: table => new
            {
                listID = table.Column<long>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                name = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
                CheckList = table.Column<long>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_List", x => x.ListID);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "CheckListItem",
            columns: table => new
            {
                CheckListItemID = table.Column<long>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                question = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
                order = table.Column<long>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                isChecked = table.Column<long>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_CheckListItem", x => x.CheckListItemID);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "CheckList",
            columns: table => new
            {
                CheckListID = table.Column<long>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                name = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
                CheckListItem = table.Column<long>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_CheckList", x => x.CheckListID);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_CheckList_CheckListItem_CheckListItem",
                    column: x => x.CheckListItem,
                    principalTable: "CheckListItem",
                    principalColumn: "CheckListItemID");
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_CheckList_CheckListItem",
            table: "CheckList",
            column: "CheckListItem");
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "List");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "CheckList");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "CheckListItem");
    }
}
```

Comment: [Introduction to relationships / Mapping relationships in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#mapping-relationships-in-ef-core) shows c# code `protected override void OnModelCreating...` (third code snippet). Do you have that? Show that code in your question.

Comment: The full code listing is above.  I don't have OnModelCreating; working on that now but it's giving me a "No suitable method found to override" error.  Still working on it...

Comment: It looks like you're using SQLite-net, not EF Core.

Comment: I did get this to work by using EF Core Power Tools then used the generated classes and am able to extend them into code first.  @ToolmakerSteve is right, but I didn't know the structure to start out.  I can see how everything is set now.  I am looking closer at what Peter Wessberg mentioned before I continue down this path. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite do not support foreign key in that fashion, hence the NotSupportedException.
[See documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/limitations) What you need to do is rely on the Key to the Checklist in the ChecklistsItems.

```
public class CheckList
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int CheckListID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [SQLite.MaxLength(50)]
    public string name { get; set; }
}
public class CheckListItem
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int CheckListItemID { get; set; }

    public string ItemText { get; set; }
    public bool isChecked { get; set; }
    public int ItemOrder { get; set; }

    public int CheckListID { get; set; }
}
```

As a side note, using EF is making your life much harder. It is better to follow Microsoft Recomendations and use [sqlite-net-pcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/) per [Maui documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/database-sqlite)

Comment: Thanks for that.  The one thing I like about entity is the ability for it to maintain the structure of the DB.  If I add a column, it will automatically be created in the DB.  I assume you have some experience with this based on your comment for sqlite-net-pcl?

Comment: @Zonus I love EF Core myself and use it in all other project I am part of. EF Core has been imporved over time and is today a better alternative than Dapper or NHibernate in my opinion. Regarding adding new columns, sqlite-net-pcl always check and migrate when CreateTable is called as per [Automatic Migrations](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/wiki/Automatic-Migrations)

Comment: I'm going to look closer at this and play around a bit with it.  This is a test project before I start implementing in my main app. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Interesting.  I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli    And after running through it, it appears that the primary / foreign key stuff is working in SQLite?  I ran it against the classes above and it generated the classes as listed in the edited question.